# Allow only " Shift + _ " from ignored chars

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0

I am using this code to block some keys in text box.

```
private void tb_MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle Shift case
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
        e.Handled = true;

    // Handle all other cases
    if (!e.Handled && (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.Z))
    {
        if (e.Key < Key.NumPad0 || e.Key > Key.NumPad9)
        {
            if (e.Key != Key.Back)
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This code blocks all the keys except A to Z and 0 to 9. But I also want to allow _ which you get by Shift + _ .

How to do this for only Shift + _ ?????
(All the code is on KeyDown event of Siverlight)

Comment: silverlight and asp.net have different ways of doing this.

Comment: I am using silverlight. What will be way for this?

Comment: @ Daniel A. White: yes that should be removed. Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the idea of checking the KeyPress args, since there are LOTS of cases it doesn't account for (such as alternate keyboard layouts, CAPS LOCK being on, or pasting text from the clipboard).

I see two ways of doing this properly:

1. Create a behaviour that you attach to the TextBox. The behaviour would keep track of the current text, and subscribe to the `TextChanged` event.  Whenever the event fires, the behaviour would ensure the text is valid, and if not, just set the text back to the last valid value it saw.
2. Create a subclass of TextBox, in which you override the `OnTextInput()` method.  Here you can do whatever checks you want, and if you don't like the text that was input (`e.Text`), just set `e.Handled = true` and the input will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
if ((e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift) && (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemMinus))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Is this if statement will like this
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift) && ..... AND what is Keys.OemMinus???? I am all doing this on KeyDown event.

Comment: @Waheed: If you place this statement in the KeyDown event, it will work as you expect it. The modifier keys are provided with the KeyEventArgs and `OemMinus` means the OEM key "-"; it is sent when you press the Minus / Underscore key left to the right shift key or if you press the Minus key on the number block.

Comment: This is assuming that the Underscore is reached by pressing Shift+Minus. That doesn't go for all keyboard layouts.

Comment: @Erno: If tested it on my keyboard (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 v.1.0) and it sent this kombination for pressing Shift plus the Minus / Underscore key left to the right shift key and for the kombination Shift plus Minus-Key of number block.

Comment: @Fischermaen - I was not referring to brands of keyboard but to different layouts (QWERTY, AZERTY, ...) http://www.ibt.ca/v2/items/btc5121w/images/azerty_1.jpg

Comment: @Fischermean: I am getting these vales from KeyEventArgs e.PlatformKeyCode, e.OriginalSource, e.Key, e.Handled. And I only want Underscore not the minus. In this event there is no e.Modifiers or e.KeyCode. Call you help me where is my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @Fischermaen: One thing more. I think you are telling me with  System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs BUT I am in silverlight web which uses System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs.